# how to get application name for a google doc?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to talk the google docs. I need the appcation name string. I have no idea what it is. please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This name is arbitrary. It is meant to identify your program with Google. Here's what Google says about the [`application name`](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/docs/DocsService.html):

> **applicationName** - the name of the client application accessing the service. Application names should preferably have the format [company-id]-[app-name]-[app-version]. The name will be used by the Google servers to monitor the source of authentication.
>       protocol - name of protocol to use for authentication ("http"/"https")
>       domainName - the name of the domain hosting the login handler

Comment: Thenaks Jweede.Could u tell me hw can i get for my already exisiting google docs account?